# Symfony2 upload javascript blob

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, blob

I'm trying to upload an image created with canvas to symfony using a blob.
The javascript code is working and is sending a blob. But in the controller I can't pass the validation. When I try to read the validation, it doesn't contain any errors.

Is there a problem in my Foto.php? Or is it in my controller?

Javascript to send POST:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.5);
var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);        
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Add any event handlers here...
xhr.open('POST', '{{ path("foto_uploadwebcam" ) }}', true);
xhr.send(formData);


function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

Foto.php (partially)

```
/**
* Foto
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Yeouuu\FotoBundle\Entity\FotoRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Foto
  {    
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;
private $temp;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->path;
        $this->path = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    //$this->fixOrientation($this->getAbsolutePath());
    //create polaroid
    $this->effectPolaroid($this->getAbsolutePath(), 3);

    // check if we have an old image
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        // delete the old image
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
        // clear the temp image path
        $this->temp = null;
    }
    $this->file = null;
}
}
```

And the controller:

```
public function uploadwebcamAction(Request $request)
{        

    $foto = new Foto();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($foto, array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($foto);
        $em->flush();        
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("foto_share", array('foto' => $foto->getId())));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code above, with a little adaptation I found the idea very useful for my own use!  Funny, this post is over a year old, too, just another way SO helps us all!  Sorry I don't have an answer for this, but I was curious if you ran into folder permissions for the destination the files get uploaded to?  Also, I had to add some hidden form fields in TWIG as well, including for the form tag the attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data".  This is in case anyone else stumbles onto this question and still looking for a solution!

Comment: @AaronBelchamber I'll try and update this, with an answer. I found a way to do what I needed.

Comment: @yeouuu, Instead of editing your question with an answer, you can and _should_ answer your own question. There's even a [badge for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) you'd probably have considering the views and upvotes.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Those edits are just renaming and indenting fixes...

Comment: Can you double check if you receive the file in Symfony? I had that issue in the past: Javascript was sending the file, PHP was receiving the file and Symfony not. Let me know if it is that and I will have a look to my old fix.

Comment: As @TonyChiboucas mentionned it, could you answer your question if you solved your validation problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following headers in your request:

```
enctype: multipart/form-data
```

Otherwise symfony does not recognise the "parts" and the Request->files is empty.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-enctype